# mouseMoved not called

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsview, osx-lion, nswindow

I have a subclassed `NSView` which is part of a .xib-file of a subclassed `NSDocument`, which gets alive by the default behaviour of `NSDocumentController`'s `openDocument:` method. In this subclassed `NSView` I have implemented the methods `awakeFromNib`, in which the view's `NSWindow` `setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES` method is called, and `acceptsFirstMouse:`, which returns `YES`. But my `mouseMoved:` method implementation of my subclassed `NSView` doesn't get called when I move the mouse over it. What might be the problem?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may be able to use MouseDragged. That works without an NSTrackingArea, but it only fires if the mouse is down.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't used `mouseMoved:` in a real project (I've just played around with it a little). As far as I can tell, `mouseMoved:` is only called when your view is the first responder and then not only while the mouse is over your view, but always when the mouse moves. You might be better off using an NSTrackingArea. Check the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html) for more information.

Comment: This does not answer the question really.

Comment: See below. You need a tracking area installed in order to begin receiving these events.

Answer (score 30):

Be sure to request the mouseMoved event is sent:

```
NSTrackingAreaOptions options = (NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingInVisibleRect |  
                         NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingMouseMoved);

NSTrackingArea *area = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                                    options:options
                                                      owner:self
                                                   userInfo:nil];
```

Comment: One note. I'm not sure it should be an int but rather an NSInteger type or the typedef preferably NSTrackingAreaOptions which is infinitely more readable and guaranteed to be the right type.

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't give any context as to where this should be called. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41878227/5552584 for that information.

Answer (score 21):

As noted by others, an `NSTrackingArea` is a good solution, and an appropriate place to install the tracking area is `NSView.updateTrackingAreas()`. It isn't necessary to set the containing NSWindow's `setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents` property.

In Swift 3:

```
class CustomView : NSView {

    var trackingArea : NSTrackingArea?

    override func updateTrackingAreas() {
        if trackingArea != nil {
            self.removeTrackingArea(trackingArea!)
        }
        let options : NSTrackingAreaOptions =
            [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .mouseMoved, .activeInKeyWindow]
        trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: options,
                                      owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea!)
    }

    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        Swift.print("Mouse moved: \(event)")
    }
}
```

Comment: .mouseEnteredAndExited, .mouseMoved, .activeInKeyWindow 
 => .mouseEnteredAndExited, .mouseMoved, .activeInKeyWindow

Comment: This sample code saved by day. TIL about updateTrackingAreas. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Deshitified version of @jbouwman s answer:

```
override func updateTrackingAreas() {
    self.addTrackingArea(NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .mouseMoved, .activeInKeyWindow], owner: self, userInfo: nil))
}
```

Comment: But... but... *weeps*

Comment: This will cause the tracking area to be added multiple times, which results in getting multiple mouse events. @jbouwman's code avoids that.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone else runs into this. I ran into an issue where I was subclassing a subclass and was trying to add a tracking area to both classes (for two different reasons).

If you are doing something like this, you will need to make sure that your `mouseMoved:`, etc call into the super, or only one of your subclasses will receive the message.

```
- (void) mouseMoved: (NSEvent*) theEvent
{
    // Call the super event
    [super mouseMoved: theEvent];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

oc version:

```
    - (void)updateTrackingAreas {
        [self initTrackingArea];
    }
    
    -(void) initTrackingArea {
        NSTrackingAreaOptions options = (NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingInVisibleRect |
                                 NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingMouseMoved);
    
        NSTrackingArea *area = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                                            options:options
                                                              owner:self
                                                           userInfo:nil];
        
        [self addTrackingArea:area];
    }
```